# Initialize boot paramaters screen_info with no Uefi support in bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, bootloader

I would like to make the frame buffer and thus its display available during the booting procedure when implementing a boot loader, while this boot loader shall not support UEFI.

To reach these,

1. the `struct screen_info` should be set when passing booting parameters to the kernel.
2. and the setting could follow the impl in OVMF using GOP: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/tianocore/edk2@master/-/blob/OvmfPkg/Library/LoadLinuxLib/Linux.c

Are they correct? And how could it be realized without UEFI support in this case?